# useReducer state is apparently not reactive

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I have had an idea to build a React store that is somewhat like Vuex. I want a wrapper component to receive an object of values and provide, using `useContext`, an object back that attaches a `state` and `set` to each key in the object.

For example, if you wrapped your app in something like `<StoreProvider value={{ color: 'red' }}>` you could in any child write `const { color } = useContext(StoreContext)`, use its value with `color.state`, and then call `color.set('blue')` to globally change that value.

I have written a best-attempt at the store with `useReducer`:

```
import React, {
    createContext,
    useContext,
    useReducer
} from 'react'

const StoreContext = createContext(null)
export const useStoreContext = () => useContext(StoreContext)

export const StoreProvider = ({ children, value }) => {
    
    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        state[action.type].state = action.payload
        return state
    }

    Object.keys(value).map(key => {
        let state = value[key]
        value[key] = {
            state: state,
            set: (setter) => dispatch({ type: key, payload: setter })
        }
    })
 
    const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, value)

    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
            {children}
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And a little demo to see if it works:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { StoreProvider, useStoreContext } from './store'

const App = () => {
  const { color } = useStoreContext()

  return (
    <>
    <h1>{color.state}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => color.set('yellow')}>Change color</button>
    <button onClick={() => console.log(color)}>Log</button>
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StoreProvider value={{
    color: 'orange'
  }}>
    <App />
  </StoreProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

In the above, the `<h1>` renders as 'orange' correctly, but doesn't update to 'yellow' when the `set('yellow')` is run. If I log color, however, the `state` has updated to 'yellow' -- which I guess means the state isn't reactive.

Have I done something really stupid? I'm pretty nooby with React and have never used `useReducer` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you missing a very important point in React that you should not ever mutate the state object. `state[action.type].state = action.payload` is a state mutation. On top of the mutation, you simply return the same state object. In order for React state updates to work correctly you necessarily need to return ***new*** object references.

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,                // <-- shallow copy state
    [action.type]: {
      ...state[action.type], // <-- shallow copy nested state
      state: action.payload,
    }
  };
}
```

You are also misusing the `array.map` callback; you should really use a `forEach` is you are iterating an array and issuing side-effects. `array.map` is considered a pure function.

```
Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
  let state = value[key]
  value[key] = {
    state: state,
    set: (setter) => dispatch({ type: key, payload: setter })
  }
});
```

I couldn't get your initial `value` mapping to work correctly, seems it was doing some extra nesting of properties that didn't quite match how you were accessing in the UI nor updating. I suggest the following for computing your initial reducer state value. Iterate the array of key-value pairs of the `value` object passed to the context, reducing into an object with the same keys and the value and setter nested correctly.

```
const StoreProvider = ({ children, value }) => {
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      [action.type]: {
        ...state[action.type],
        state: action.payload
      }
    };
  };

  const state = Object.entries(value).reduce(
    (state, [key, value]) => ({
      ...state,
      [key]: {
        state: value,
        set: (setter) => dispatch({ type: key, payload: setter })
      }
    }),
    {}
  );

  const [store, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, state);

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit usereducer-state-is-apparently-not-reactive]

Comment: This works exactly how I envisioned! Using `reduce` was definitely smart. I also didn't know you could assign values to specific object keys with brackets inside the spread object.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @yip_yip Welcome. Overall I think you should invest in learning the "React ways" of state management, but it was an interesting use-case. I don't see this being practical or maintainable when the state shape becomes more complex and you start adding levels of depth and nesting/organization of your state. The reducer function abstracts this structure from the UI, and notice in your case you still needed to implement the [immutable update pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify your logic using the useState hook in this case as long as the state to manage is not so complex:

```
export const StoreProvider = ({ children, value }) => {
  const { color } = value;

  const [currentColor, setCurrentColor] = useState(color);

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{ currentColor, setCurrentColor }}>
      {children}
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And here you App component:

```
const App = () => {
  const { currentColor, setCurrentColor } = useStoreContext();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{currentColor}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentColor('yellow')}>Change color</button>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(currentColor)}>Log</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: While the example I wrote above only has one value to track, the goal would be that you pass an object of every state value you want to track, which could include many keys, each with a key.state and key.set()